# React Router always renders NotFound default component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I've been searching all over the internet for solutions but alas I come here for some help. The problem is that the URL changes but the respective component in `Route` don't render, instead of that, the `NotFoundPage` is rendered.

Here's the `App.js` `Router` code:

```
<Router history={history}>
   <Switch>
     <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
     <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
     <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
     <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here's `PrivateRoute` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

The problem I'm facing is the when I go to `/` the `NotFoundPage` is rendered instead of `LoginPage` **but** the URL correctly redirects and changes to `/login`. But when I refresh, the `LoginPage` is rendered. Similarly, when I click on link that takes to `/register` from `LoginPage` the URL changes but `RegisterPage` doesn't render it's the same `NotFoundPage`.

Comment: did you try put exact  on login and register ?

Comment: yeah, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: do you use Link from react-router instead <a>  ??

Comment: yes, I use `Link` instead of `<a>`.

Comment: can you reproduce this problem in minimal version  on (https://codesandbox.io/) ??

Comment: i'm guessing but in my projects i use BrowserRouter not Router. and then you don't have to use custom history.If you don't need custom history object use BrowserRouter. take a look on docs paragraph about [Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router)

Comment: I'm using [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) to push routes programmatically when required based on certain conditions so I thought of using `Router`. And one more thing that's consuming me is that `Router` should work if I'm managing the history myself and implementation seems ok. Share your GitHub username if you need access to codebase. I made it public earlier and shared it here but due to several issues I had to make it private.

Comment: (https://github.com/robert8888)

Comment: ok. but for test you can switch on BroswerRouter and then we can check this clue

Comment: I've added you to the repo.

Comment: i switched to `BrowserRouter` and that was working fine but i wanted to know why's the error occurring with `Router` implementation.

Comment: Although in `BrowserRouter` also homepage after successful login is coming blank. most probably because `history.push` being used to go to `/` after login.

Comment: ps. you should store password in store, anywhere :) ... because when you use BroswerRouter you don't have your history ? so redirect can don't work. you can make redirect from login page using this.props.history.push({pathname: "/"})

Comment: you can acces to history from props when you using broswerRouter so you can push in page component [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

Comment: note that in docs. args of history.push is location object with pathname !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223638/discussion-between-mayank-and-robert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During contribution on github we figured solution.

This weird behavior flows from using custom history.

```
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={customHistory} />, node);
```

When it is used then somehow router don't react to changes in a location path.
Until you don't add:

```
<Switch location={window.location}>
```

According to the docs the location in switch by default is set to window. location but for some reason when you don't use BroswerRouter or StackRouter but just Router this starts working when we directly set location.